# How to make my Ajax method to call a method from controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, ajax

I have a .NET 6 project where I have a service sending an email and return a bool on success. I have a controller calling that method and return JSON (value success). I also have a view where the form is and where I have my Ajax method to call the method from the controller.

The issue is, when I click on the submit button to submit my form I cannot reach the break point on the method in the controller, so I think that the Ajax method is not calling properly. But the page just reloads.

Controller Method:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> PreInscription([FromBody]
PreInscription preInscription){

    var inscriptionService =
    serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IInscriptionService>();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var isSend = await
        inscriptionService.SendEmailPreInscription(preInscription);

            if (isSend)
                return Json(new { response = "success" });
        }
        return Json(new { response = "failed" });
}
```

View:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

    function runMethod(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.ActionLink("PreInscription", "Inscription")',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'Json',
            async: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('form').submit(function () {
            runMethod();
        });

    });
</script>


<form asp-action="">
  <button id="submitButton" class="btn btn-large btn-theme margintop10"
    type="submit">Envoyer</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there are a few issues in your code. Let's go through them step by step and correct them:

Controller Method Parameters:
Your controller method PreInscription takes a parameter of type PreInscription, but your AJAX call doesn't include any data in the request body. You should pass the data from your form to the server. You can use serialize() to do this.

Prevent Default Form Submission:
To prevent the form from being submitted traditionally, you should use event.preventDefault() in your submit event handler.

Alert Display: When displaying the JSON response, you should specify response.response since your JSON response contains a property named "response."

Here's the corrected code:

Controller Method:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> PreInscription([FromBody] PreInscription preInscription)
{
    var inscriptionService = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IInscriptionService>();

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var isSend = await inscriptionService.SendEmailPreInscription(preInscription);

        if (isSend)
            return Json(new { response = "success" });
    }
    return Json(new { response = "failed" });
}
```

View:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    function runMethod() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("PreInscription", "YourControllerName")',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({ /* Your form data here */ }), // Pass form data
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response.response); // Use response.response to access the JSON property
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('form').submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default form submission
            runMethod();
        });
    });
</script>

<form asp-controller="YourControllerName" asp-action="PreInscription">
    <!-- Your form fields here -->
    <button id="submitButton" class="btn btn-large btn-theme margintop10" type="submit">Envoyer</button>
</form>
```

Replace "YourControllerName" with the actual name of your controller where the PreInscription action is located.

In the data field of your AJAX call, you should pass the actual form data that you want to submit to the server. You can use jQuery's serialize() function to serialize the form data. Make sure your form fields have proper name attributes that match the properties of the PreInscription model.

With these changes, your form should now submit the data via AJAX to the controller's PreInscription method, and you should be able to reach the breakpoint in your controller.

Comment: @Adriel: [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) (or similar) does get lucky from time to time (usually not).